# How to find where a query is being stored/executed from (SQL Server 2008)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to speed up a process that is running rather slow. I was able to find the culprit using

```
SELECT TOP 100 *
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats qs
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.sql_handle) qt
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(qs.plan_handle) qp
WHERE qs.last_execution_time > '2021-06-28 00:00:00.000'
ORDER BY qs.total_logical_reads DESC
```

I am able to refactor to speed it up. Issue is the query is stored in plain text and I can only find it from the table

```
sys.dm_exec_sql_text
```

and dbid and objectid are both null. Furthermore I didn't write the query so I'm not really sure where to start

My SQL isn't great so I'm not even sure if its possible to track this down but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure it's not an ad-hoc batch?

Comment: @Charlieface I think you might be right . I have tried the solution and I can seem to find it anywhere on the database. I also tried a text search looking to see if it was stored in any columns in any tables still nothing :( . What I don't understand is that every time I try and load a record on the front end I see the same query being executed from sys.dm_exec_sql_text table. Some automated process is triggering its execution.

Comment: you say that the problematic query is executed everytime you add a record ?
Could it be an 'insert trigger' on the table that is being added to ?

Comment: If it is an adhoc batch you can use the sys.sessions table ro see who is executing it. You can also can also get more info from query stats table

Comment: @PeterTilsted I checked triggers under the table and unfortunately nothing is matching what I am looking for. I am pretty sure the issue is with the sql that was written for the front end, for which I have no access too and isn't stored as a procedure. It is probably hidden in the project files somewhere :(